# match characters from different sheet and dirrefernt field with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to this forum and Vba.I have a bank statement to reconcile which is contain few characters on the " detail" field match to my "info" sheet client list. the charges and interest need to find automatically my default nominal list in "info " sheet.id it possible to match with a vba button?please see my attched sample work sheet.

[my attchment](https://www.dropbox.com/s/of9yyyyupia9jbe/TEST.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Paste your code here, and tell us what is wrong with it. We will gladly help.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/of9yyyyupia9jbe/TEST.xlsm?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to "match with a VBA button".

Comment: thanks for the quick reply vasip can you please help me on this

Comment: Hi Vasip please see below the link I ve attached in drop box https://www.dropbox.com/s/of9yyyyupia9jbe/TEST.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Hi Centhuran, I do accept contractor jobs, but not on SO. Look for a payed employee or a contractor around your location, or on sites like freelancer.com. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. If you don't want to pay for the job to be done, try learning VBA and do it yourself. If you get stuck with the code and got a programming question, come back to SO, we will gladly help. Best of luck!

Comment: Hi Vasip Can you tel me roughly how much it will cost?

Comment: Hi Xenthusan. Nope. StackOvwerflow is no place for that.

Comment: Thanks Guys, Ive manage to write a code to open folde from specific cell reference but in that folder its not opening xls or pdf files .can you please help me .please see the code below

Comment: Sub open folder()
     
    Dim strPath As String
     
    Const RootPath As String = "Z:\DBASE\CLIENTS\"
     
    strPath = [E13].Value
    If Dir(RootPath & strPath & "\", vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
         
         
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
            .InitialFileName = RootPath & strPath
            .Show
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox " The path " & RootPath & strPath & " does not exist.", vbExclamation, "Error"
    End If
     
End Sub